# Copy row of data from one pandas dataframe to another

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

A pandas newbie here. I imported an excel data into pandas, I want to copy subset of data of a specific row (placeholder) from one dataframe (Error_data1) to another dataframe (Error_data2) where the 'placeholder' exists.

Here is the first 4 rows of Error_data1 (it has 150 rows)

```
index    student  Error1   Error2    Error3    Error4   Error5
0        Henry    2.5647   -0.2145   1.3524    2.0124   6.2013
1        John     -0.0124  1.0365    3.2145    4.0211   -5.0124
2        Terry    1.1120   2.2154    -6.2013   1.2032   2.3321
3        Gerald   9.2105   1.0212    3.2548    3.6478   4.1020
```

Here is the first 5 rows of Error_data2 (it has 358 rows)

```
index  Day   Time  student  Error1   Error2    Error3    Error4   Error5
0      Mon   01:00  Terry    
1      Tue   05:15  John     
2      Wed   05:25  john     
3      Wed   12:15  Gerald   
4      Thur  11:00   Henry
```

Here is the code i tried

```
for i in range(len(Error_data1)):
    if Error_data1['Student'][i] == Error_data2['Student'][i]:
        a = Error_data1.iloc[i,1:6]
        Error_data2.iloc[i,4:9] = a
```

I expect Error_data2 to look like this:

```
index  Day   Time  student  Error1   Error2    Error3    Error4   Error5
0      Mon   01:00  Terry    1.1120   2.2154    -6.2013   1.2032   2.3321
1      Tue   05:15  John    -0.0124  1.0365    3.2145    4.0211   -5.0124 
2      Wed   05:25  john    -0.0124  1.0365    3.2145    4.0211   -5.0124 
3      Wed   12:15  Gerald   9.2105   1.0212    3.2548    3.6478   4.1020 
4      Thur  11:00   Henry   2.5647   -0.2145   1.3524    2.0124   6.2013
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try merging the two dataframes on student names.

```py
combined = Error_data1.merge(Error_data2, on='student', how='left').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It didn't work. I got an error message : 

ValueError: left keys must be sorted

Comment: try using reset_index(inplace =True, drop=True) before the merge operation.

Comment: i tried this: Error_data1.reset_index(inplace =True, drop=True)
Error_data2.reset_index(inplace =True, drop=True). but i still got the same error message: ValueError: left keys must be sorted

Comment: Error_data1 = Error_data1.sort_values('student')

Comment: i got error: right keys must be sorted. Then i tried Error_data1 = Error_data1.sort_values('student')
Error_data2 = Error_data2.sort_values('student') and got :                 
TypeError: No matching signature found

Comment: 1. you need to change lower case names to upper case names as well like john. 2. I have made changes,

Comment: NP! could you upvote my answer and mark it as correct?